# PowerShell - Transfer Files Using BITS protocol as a scheduled task - not working when logged off

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, bit

I have written a PowerShell script which uses the BITS transfer protocol in order to transfer large files from Source machine to destination machine. When I run the PowerShell script manually logging into my destination remote machine (where the files need to be copied) then the files are getting copied without any issues.

But When I have created a scheduled task that runs the PowerShell script daily at a particular time. It is throwing the following error

> The operation being requested was not performed because the user has not logged on to the network. The specified service does not exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800704DD)

The script is getting worked only when I log-in to my destination machine where the file is being copied. If at all I log off from that machine at that scheduled task time then I am getting the error.  Please suggest what needs to be done in order to make the scheduled task run even if I log off from that machine.

Comment: Are you sure you set the 'run whether the user is logged on or not' option in TS manually of via PoSH and set the correct credentials for it to run?

Comment: Yes i have set the option to run the scheduled task whether the user is logged in or not and even provided the user credentials needed for it to run. Even then i am getting the error

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation about BITS found on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362708(v=vs.85).aspx (and the specific Powershell documentation found on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663885(v=vs.85).aspx) the user that created the jobs has to be logged on.

Powershell Doc :
Important  
When you use *-BitsTransfer cmdlets from within a process that runs in a noninteractive context, such as a Windows service, you may not be able to add files to BITS jobs, which can result in a suspended state. For the job to proceed, the identity that was used to create a transfer job must be logged on. For example, when creating a BITS job in a PowerShell script that was executed as a Task Scheduler job, the BITS transfer will never complete unless the Task Scheduler's task setting "Run only when user is logged on" is enabled

Generic documentation :
BITS continues to transfer files after an application exits if the user who initiated the transfer remains logged on and a network connection is maintained. BITS will not force a connection.
BITS suspends the transfer if a connection is lost or if the user logs off. BITS persists transfer information while the user is logged off, across network disconnects, and during computer restarts.

In short : what you want is not possible.

(this is one of the reasons why you should always read the documentation when encountering problems like these)

Comment: Hello bluuf, For your kind information, Before starting the implementation of the PowerShell Script related to transfer of large files using BITS transfer protocol i have read the documentation carefully. Our previous requirement is to run the PS scrpt manually by logging into the machine. So now we thought of doing it an automated process instead of running the script manually and chose to have a scheduled task  so that it gets completed without human intervention. I have just posted to know if there are any work around.

Comment: @kamal : if the documentation speficly tells you that a user has to be logged on then you already had the answer to start with. This is how BITS is designed.